# Wordpress: Display author's drafts and pending review posts in frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I need a way to make users view the drafts and pending review of the posts that he published . Without getting to the dashboard - which means from the frontend.

I want each to be in a different page than the other.

I tried this function in my custom template but unfortunately it didn't work.

```
<?php query_posts('&post_type=post&post_status=draft'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to call `query_posts()` with an array as argument. Try this:

```
<?php
$args= array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'draft'
);
query_posts($args);
?>
```

Insert this just before the start of *the Loop* in your page template.

Source: [WordPress › Support > How-To and Troubleshooting](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-list-of-drafts-to-subscribers#post-1373098).